# Azure AD Graph API: List Directory Objects

Tags: api, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to get a list of Azure AD Directories that I have via the API? I am able to access the Azure AD Graph API to get the user/group information for each specific directory, however, I would like to list all directories that are associated with my Azure subscription.

If necessary, I could even query each directory individually. I just want to list out the directories however possible. But, looking at the output for users, groups, and directory roles, I have yet to see any property that actually shows the directory object's display name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've yet to discover an endpoint that can list all of AD tenants, but you can get the [TenantDetails](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#TenantDetailEntity) for a tenant via the `/tenantDetails` endpoint.

Sample output (using a yet-to-be-release Ruby gem that I'm working on):

```
#
# ids and names obfuscated...
#
[2] pry(main)> client.get('/tenantDetails').docs
=> [{"odata.type"=>"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.TenantDetail",
  "objectType"=>"Company",
  "objectId"=>"38041ede-...",
  "deletionTimestamp"=>nil,
  "assignedPlans"=>
   [{"assignedTimestamp"=>"2015-10-27T18:55:12Z", "capabilityStatus"=>"Enabled", "service"=>"AccessControlServiceKey", "servicePlanId"=>"e4f8ab60-..."},
    {"assignedTimestamp"=>"2015-10-23T15:13:34Z", "capabilityStatus"=>"Enabled", "service"=>"AccessControlServiceS2S", "servicePlanId"=>"11d043ce-..."},
    {"assignedTimestamp"=>"2015-10-23T15:13:34Z", "capabilityStatus"=>"Enabled", "service"=>"AccessControlServiceS2S", "servicePlanId"=>"11d043ce-..."},
    {"assignedTimestamp"=>"2015-10-23T15:13:34Z", "capabilityStatus"=>"Enabled", "service"=>"AccessControlServiceS2S", "servicePlanId"=>"11d043ce-..."}],
  "city"=>nil,
  "companyLastDirSyncTime"=>nil,
  "country"=>nil,
  "countryLetterCode"=>"US",
  "dirSyncEnabled"=>nil,
  "displayName"=>"AD Testing...",
  "marketingNotificationEmails"=>["marketing@..."],
  "postalCode"=>nil,
  "preferredLanguage"=>"en",
  "provisionedPlans"=>
   [{"capabilityStatus"=>"Enabled", "provisioningStatus"=>"Success", "service"=>"AccessControlServiceS2S"}, {"capabilityStatus"=>"Enabled", "provisioningStatus"=>"Success", "service"=>"AccessControlServiceS2S"}],
  "provisioningErrors"=>[],
  "securityComplianceNotificationMails"=>[],
  "securityComplianceNotificationPhones"=>[],
  "state"=>nil,
  "street"=>nil,
  "technicalNotificationMails"=>["craig@..."],
  "telephoneNumber"=>nil,
  "verifiedDomains"=>[{"capabilities"=>"Email, OfficeCommunicationsOnline", "default"=>true, "id"=>"00057...", "initial"=>true, "name"=>"....onmicrosoft.com", "type"=>"Managed"}]}]
```

Comment: Is there any way we can find tenant of an user by email. We may not be member of that tenant (not even same subscription)

Comment: Or did you find a way to list all tenants